# Logging into a page Jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to log in and fetch data from this page https://www.workplaceonline.com.au/c2/signin/ using jsoup

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
 Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://workplaceonline.com.au/c2/signin/")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://workplaceonline.com.au/c2/signin/")
            .data("cookieexists", "false")
            .data("account", "myAccount")
            .data("username", "myUsername")
            .data("password", "MyPassword")
            .data("task", "Sign+In")
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .post();


    System.out.println(doc);
```

When I run the code it prints the HTML for the login screen, indicating that it has failed to login properly
This is what is shown in the network panel when successfully logged in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5AIP.jpg

Comment: looks like your login attempt failed.

Comment: there is a "task" parameter too.add it and check again.we can't test cuz don't know loggin details

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure why. All the credentials are correct, I just tested them by copy and pasting them from the code into the browser

Comment: Updated the code and put the task parameter in, but its still outputting the login page

Comment: Try to change the user agent string, check also the headers exchanged between the browser and the website. More over compare the exchanges between your code and the website with those between the browser and the site. A tool like Fiddler can help on this.

Comment: Does the order matter? Seems like useragent  should be passed first, also if they're checking it maybe it should be valid? Maybe you need to follow redirects as well?